# What is the explanation for Aitareya Brahmana III. 3

Tags: vedas, explanation

> Therefore, there are several wives for one man, but not several husbands for a woman simultaneously - Aitareya Brahmana III. 3.

Can we thus conclude, using the above verse, that polygyny is allowed and polyandry forbidden?

---

<sup>[Source](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45039/22556) of this verse is an answer that I found on this site</sup>

Comment: Yes it is. It is cited by Bharuci in his commentary on the Manusmriti in the section on marriage.

Comment: @Vivikta thanks for the edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Was Polyandry allowed prior to Mahabharata?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/6741/was-polyandry-allowed-prior-to-mahabharata)

Comment: @Archit how is this answering my question. It is about the verse explaining and not about Mahabharata.

Comment: Because I didn’t read the based on the above verse part sorry. Accha anyway if you rely on the above verse then it’s very clear, doesn’t call for a doubt. But if you want to know whether polyandry is actually allowed or not then reading the linked answer will answer your question.

Comment: @Archit okk, anyway thanks for the link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *Can we thus conclude, using the above verse, that polygyny is allowed and polyandry forbidden?*

Yes. P. V. Kane cites this verse in the chapter on polygamy in [*History of Dharmaśāstra, Vol II Part I*](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.24397/page/n608/mode/1up):

> The [Tai. S. (VI. 6.4.3)](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/yv/yv06.htm) gives a dogmatic and somewhat picturesque explanation of polygamy that 'on one sacrificial post he passes round two girdles, so one man secures two wives; that he does not pass one girdle round two posts, so one wife does not obtain two husbands'. **The [Ait. Br. (12.11)](https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104263/page/n137/mode/1up) similarly declares 'therefore one man has many wives, but one wife has not many husbands at the same time'.**

Medhātithi, commenting on [Manu 9.101](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201468.html), also uses the same verse in support of his argument that men are allowed to take more than one wife:

> ‘May **mutual fidelity** continue till death’,—this, in brief should be understood as the highest duty between husband and wife.—(9.101)
>
> *Medhātithi’s commentary (manubhāṣya):*
>
> ‘Fidelity’—unstinted obedience in all actions. Says Āpastamba: (a) ‘The wife should not be neglected in matters relating to Duties, Wealth and Pleasure’;—(b) ‘The highest good of man consists in Duty, Wealth and Pleasure, as it is declared that the whole fabric rests upon these three factors.’
>
> Some people hold the following view:—
>
> > “What is meant by ‘fidelity’ here is non-abandonment; otherwise, as to the woman, **so to the man also, it would not be open to many more than one wife.**”
>
> **This however is not right; because in regard to men there is a distinct sanction**—(a) ‘Those who act through mere lust, etc.,’ (b) ‘the barren wife shall be superseded in the eighth year,’ and so forth; while there is no such sanction in the case of women. **There is another text also which is indicative of the same fact—‘There are several wives for one man, but not several husbands for a woman at the same time.’**
>
> ‘Until death,’—till they die; i.e., it ends only when either of them dies.
>
> This should be understood to be the highest duty of man and wife, stated in brief.—(101)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell how many women can a man marry maximum (limit).

Comment: "The barren wife shall be superseded in the eighth year; in the tenth she whose children die off; in the eleventh she who bears only daughters; but immediately she who talks harshly.—([Manu 9.81](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc201444.html))" - so there's no limit...

Comment: @sv in your reference link has mis-interpretation. Last line says "As regards the wife who is harsh of speech, as there is no such serious defect, there need be no supersession; and she may be forgiven." But its the opposite. She should be left immediately, as per manusmiriti.

Comment: @Yatix how do you know

Comment: @DarkKnight Bcoz I checked multiple other references and in proper english it will mean same. I guess interpreter assumed it based on current moral standards. Harsh words are not accepted a some crime but mentally its a disaster. Having it 24 x 7 will be equivalent to hell.

Comment: @Yatix so what do you think about the translation of Aitareya Brahmana III. 3.

Comment: @DarkKnight Can you point me to the reference link of that particular verse? I dont see it in question.

Comment: @Yatix it's in the question. >"Source of this verse is an answer that I found on this site"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122759/discussion-between-yatix-and-dark-knight).

Comment: @Yatix Good observation. Strange interpretation of Manu 9.81 by Medhātithi. Maybe he was trying to save marriages from ending too quickly.

Comment: @sv. For sure. But we know what is wrong but emotions and serial drama has currupted our mind.

Comment: You can find the original verse from AB here: http://titus.uni-frankfurt.de/texte/etcs/ind/aind/ved/rv/ab/ab.htm?ab094.htm (tasmād ekasya bahvyo jāyā bʰavanti, naikasyai bahavaḥ patayo) and the English translation here: https://archive.org/details/in.ernet.dli.2015.104263 @Yatix

Comment: @sv. Look they have copyright for this material. Lol.

Comment: @Yatix Didn't get you. What's wrong with copyrighting a translation/transliteration?

Comment: I mean the verses itself, not the translation.