# "When Smriti conflicts with Sruti, Sruti should be followed" - which SRUTI says this?

Tags: smriti, sruti

Quote which **Sruti** (Veda) says "Sruti is more important/takes precedence over Smriti".

To clarify, in case it wasn't already crystal clear - DO NOT quote **Smriti**

Comment: tagging @SwamiVishwananda

Comment: tagging @PradipGangopadhyay

Comment: I guess one response will be along lines of - *'Smriti came after Sruti, so how can Sruti mention it?'*

Comment: I understand this does not answer your question but Shankara mentions in brahmasutra bhashya 2.1.1 that only those Smritis that follow Sruti must be considered as authoritative. Apparently, this comes from mimamsa sutra 1.3.3, and is accepted by Shankara.

Comment: In the same place (BSB 2.1.1), its accepted by Shankara that when Smriti contradicts Sruti, the former is discarded. This is one of the reasons for rejecting SAmkhya Smritis.

Comment: @zero - pls locate/quote mimamsa sutra 1.3.3, and examples of any such contradiction followed by discard-ation.

Comment: Please check here - https://archive.org/details/mimamsasutra00jaimuoft/page/24/mode/1up

Comment: For examples of such discarding, its the Samkhya smritis.

Comment: @zero - thanks.

Comment: Shruti doesn't quote it because "Shruti" doesn't even know the existence of any of Medival Era Smritis. Instead of violent comments, evidence of Smritis in Shruti would be better to show.

Comment: Thats why Smritis tell you to "rationally" study and interpret Vedas and anything which is Anti Vedic (Not Anti Smriti) is bound to fail. So says Manu Smriti 12.106

Comment: Kumārila, Ślokavārtika, 2.14.—‘The fact of these acts being conducive to good is, <<<in every case, learnt from the Veda>>>; and in this sense are they regarded as Dharma; and for this reason Dharma is not perceptible by the senses.’
Jaimini, Mīmāṃsā-Sūtra, 1.1.2.—‘Dharma is that which is described in the Veda as conducive to good.’
Not able to recollect verse where Manu says Kingdoms fail because of Anti Vedic processes.

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - Not true. See this answer https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/31999/18974  . Vedas say whatever Manu has said i.e. Manusmriti , is to be accepted

Comment: Did you even read the context ? Look at the meaning narrated in that particular context. What Yajna it is refering to. Why Manu is mentioned. : )
There are also verses saying Bramhin is Cow Sudra is Horse. It is Brahmanam so Symbolic not an independent book. @Carmensandiego

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru - Did you read bhashyas by traditional acharyas on this verse? If so , please share

Comment: @SethuSrivatsaKoduru **Not able to recollect verse where Manu says Kingdoms fail because of Anti Vedic processes.** I am asking this question out of curiosity and not in the sense of challenging. There are many examples of kingdoms that did not follow vedas - like Mughals or Romans etc. In modern day, no nation follows vedas. How is the success of these kingdoms and nations explained then?

Comment: Perhaps Manu was indicating the kind of standards or lifestyle or philosophical knowledge which in his opinion would not be maintained in a Non Vedic Kingdom. @zero

Comment: @mar As quoted [here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45040/20129), the Veda (Taittiriya samhita 2.2.10.2) says, “whatever Manu said is medicine”. So Manusmriti among Smritis has the highest authority by the Shruti itself. Other dharmashastras too derive their authority taking Manu as a base. So One will have to see what was actually said by Manu.